# DB Polling in WSO2 ESB or PS

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am writing some business flow using WSO2 Process Server. I want to start a process when there is any new entry in a specific table. i.e. we do DB Polling in oracle process.
So whenever there is a new entry in table, i need to fetch those data and start processing on those data using BPEL.

Answer (score 0):

The above explained scenario can be achieved using task component of WSO2 ESB. Using task component we can schedule the call to a proxy service after certain interval and we can use that proxy to fetch the data from database.